# Navigate to Declaration (F3 or CTRL+Click) - show file in Navigator

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse to develop Flex application for a while and after I upgraded to Eclipse 3.4.1, I noticed that whenever I CTRL+Click a type to navigate to it's declaration, the editor will open on the selected type, but it won't "Navigate" to file on the Flex Navigator tree.

I've checked that this is not the default behavior on my co-workers Eclipse, as theirs will highlight the recently opened file on the Navigator.

I've search everywhere on Eclipse Preferences but couldn't see a toggle for that. Anyone knows where I'm supposed to enable that?

Thanks!

Comment: In the upper left corner of the navigator, is there a "Link with Editor" toggle? That's the setting in the base Navigator and Java package explorer.

Comment: That Link with Editor toggle solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the flex part of it, but in eclipse there is a "Link With Editor" button in the explorer window (looks like a left and right arrow stacked).  Click that and see if it starts to behave like you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be hidden on a preferences page. :)